# How to access attributes within Angularjs's v1.5 component?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, web-component

I am using the v1.5 component, which is essentially (as far as my understanding extends) a wrapper for best practice directives.

More info about the 1.5 release of component can be found here: http://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/

I have the following:

```
<span>Correclty showing: {{ data.type }}</span>
<book class="details" type="data.type"></book>
```

And it's component definition:

```
angular
.module('app')
.component('book', {
    bindings: {
        type: '='
    },
    template: function($element, $attrs) {
        // Have tried A):
        // console.log($attrs.type); // <- undefined

        // And B):
        $attrs.$observe('type', function(value) {
            console.log(value); // <- undefined
        });

        // But.. C):
        return "This works though {{ book.type }}"; // <- renders
    }
});
```

Both `A)` and `B)` variations return `undefined`. `C)` renders correctly.

Is there a way to access attributes within the template function before returning the template string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In 1.5, templateUrl now takes injectables according to the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component.  If you use [ng-srict-di](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) you will get an error unless you specify the injectables....I'm using [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to save the headaches and keep the code clean.  Here's an example (in TypeScript):

```
  import IRootElementService = angular.IRootElementService;
  import IAttributes = angular.IAttributes;

  angular.module('app').component('book', {

      /*@ngInject*/
      templateUrl($element:IRootElementService, $attrs:IAttributes) {
           // access to the $element or $attrs injectables
      }

  });
```

or without ng-annotate in vanilla JS:

```
  angular.module('app').component('book', {    
      templateUrl: ['$element', '$attrs', function($element, $attrs) {
           // access to the $element or $attrs injectables
      }],
  });
```

Comment: I'm seeing ng-strict-di, ng-annotate, and then a very interesting @ngInject?  Can you clarify how an attr can be an injectable?  I am looking for an answer suggesting how to create the templateUrl based on other dependencies.

Comment: It's in the Angular 1.5 docs, in the component architecture, $element and $attrs are injectable.  See the component guide linked in the answer for more details.

Comment: @Jeff is it necessary to inject the $element service? I tried without injecting it and it seems to work anyway.

Comment: is there a reason you're using templateUrl vs template here? Typically I have something like `templateUrl: '/path/toHTML.html' How would I have access to the $element in that separate HTML file?